# Is there more than just one term?

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the fourth term of $(2+y)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Wouldn't it just be $\sqrt{(2+y)}$? So isn't it just one term?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series, presumably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(a+b)^n=a^nb^0+\frac{n}1a^{n-1}b^1+\frac{n(n-1)}{1\times2}a^{n-2}b^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{1\times2\times3}a^{n-3}b^3+\dots$$

Plugging in values and taking the fourth term:

$$\begin{align}
4th\text{ term of }(2+y)^{1/2} & =\frac{1/2(1/2-1)(1/2-2)}{1\times2\times3}2^{1/2-3}y^3 \\
& =\frac{\sqrt2}2y^3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2} }=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{2}  \choose n}x^{n}\quad {\text{ for all }}|x|<1$$
$${\alpha  \choose n}=\prod _{k=1}^{n}{\frac {\alpha -k+1}{k}}={\frac {\alpha (\alpha -1)\cdots (\alpha -n+1)}{n!}}.$$

$$(2+y)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{2}(1+\frac{y}{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$